# Getting error while using fuzzywuzzy: UserWarning: Using slow pure-python SequenceMatcher. Install python-Levenshtein to remove this warning

Tags: python, fuzzywuzzy, sequencematcher

I am getting below error. Is there any way to fix it without installing python-Levenshtein and if not then how to install python-Levenshtein on linux.

```
UserWarning: Using slow pure-python SequenceMatcher. Install python-Levenshtein to remove this warning
  warnings.warn
```

Comment: Just as information, fuzzywuzzy sequence matcher is purely python based (unlike numpy, elastic search etc which are based on "C"). This results in much slower process than any matcher which is based on C. That is why the warning shows up.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

First of all its a warning.

You can install python-Levenshtein using pip

```
pip install python-Levenshtein
```

You may have to change to pip3 incase if you are using python 3

Comment: Except that for some of us, the operation is MUCH MUCH MUCH slower after having installed that. It may be that I'm using it wrong.

Answer (score 3):

I was getting this same error in my Windows 10 setup. When I tried `pip install python-Levenshtein` I got

> Requirement already satisfied: python-Levenshtein in ...

I uninstalled using `pip uninstall python-Levenshtein` and reinstalled it. And the error is gone.

Answer (score 1):

You may ignore the **warning** by using the -W flag. Note that it  will silent ALL warnings. I'd suggest just installing python-levenshtein module as Preetham suggested.

```
python -W ignore foo.py
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install python-Levenshtein using pip3 or pip

pip3 install python-Levenshtein
You may have to change to pip in case if you are using python2